# How to use gnu-parallel for processing a script with two inputs?

Tags: parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I am trying to run a Python script with two inputs as follows. I got ~300 of these two inputs so I wonder if somebody could advise how to run them with parallel.

The single run looks like:

```
python stable.py KOG_1.fan KOG_1.fasta > KOG_1.stable
```

My test with parallel which is not working:

```
ls *.fan; ls *.fasta | parallel python stable.py {} {} > {.}.stable
```

but how do I specify that is has to run with `_1.fan` and `_1.fasta`; then `_2.fan` and `_1.fasta` and so on... until `_300.fan` and `_300.fasta`.

Comment: shouldn't it be _2.fasta the second time?

Comment: removed the useless phrases. They are deprecated on SO, please don't add them back.

Answer (score 2):

This is not really a Python question, it's a question about GNU parallel. You could try this if all files are prefixed with "KOG_":

```
seq 1 300 | parallel python stable.py KOG_{}.fan KOG_{}.fasta ">" KOG_{.}.stable
```

The quotes around the redirect (`">"`) are important, unless you want all of the output in one file.

To handle generic prefixes:

```
ls *fan *fasta | parallel ---max-lines=2 python stable.py {1} {2} ">" {1.}.stable
```

This uses the `-max-lines` option to take 2 lines per command. Of course this works only if the `*.fan` and `*.fasta` files match up, i.e. there must be the same number of each, and the numbers need to match up, otherwise you'll end up pairing files that shouldn't be paired. If that is a problem, you can figure out a command that will more robustly feed pairs to `parallel`.

Comment: Thank you. I will amend the question. Yes it is a GNU-parallel question indeed. I am new with GNU but I have found it is very useful. I am using a mac so try to switch GNU based thins like GNU-sed.

Comment: Thank you so much for the one liner it works perfect by using seq 1 300. Luckily all my files have the same prefix KOG_ and also are paired. You have give to my day a brilliant start.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
parallel python stable.py {} {.}.fasta '>' {.}.stable ::: *fan
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you split this task in two steps:

1. **Create a jobs file containing all commands you want to run with 
   parallel.**
   You need to create a text file `jobs.txt` that should be similar to the one presented bellow:

   ```
   python stable.py KOG_1.fan KOG_1.fasta > KOG_1.stable
   python stable.py KOG_2.fan KOG_2.fasta > KOG_2.stable
   python stable.py KOG_3.fan KOG_3.fasta > KOG_3.stable
   python stable.py KOG_4.fan KOG_4.fasta > KOG_4.stable
   ...
   python stable.py KOG_300.fan KOG_300.fasta > KOG_300.stable
   ```

   If all your files are prefixed with KOG, you can build up this file this way:

   ```
   for I in `seq 300`; do echo "python stable.py KOG_$I.fan KOG_$I.fasta > KOG_$I.stable" >> jobs.txt; done;
   ```
2. **Run parallel using the jobs file**

   Once you have the jobs file, you just need to run the following command:

   ```
   parallel -j4 < jobs.txt
   ```

   Note that `-j4` indicates that at most 4 commands from your jobs file will be running in parallel. You can adjust that according to the number of cores available on your computer.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried option number 1 and it works very well!